# Magento 2 URL Rewrite data share to Elastic Search

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

I want to share my Url rewrite Data to Elastic search, So is there any common function for Tracking URL when Product add/update/, Category add/update, Product import etc when URL is change or update.